# Append number to front of string with leading 0

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, append, prefix

How do I correctly replace the first character with 'M'?  Suppose you have a PATIENT_ID_NONNUM = 'M001', and we want 1001 as a result.

```
UPDATE [HIMC_I2B2_LZ-PROD].[dbo].[I2B2_SRC_BIOMETRICS]
SET PATIENT_ID = CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,0),'1' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),PATIENT_ID))
WHERE SUBSTRING(PATIENT_ID_NONNUM, 1, 1) = 'M'
```

EDIT:

```
UPDATE [HIMC_I2B2_LZ-PROD].[dbo].[I2B2_SRC_MEDICATION]
SET PATIENT_ID = CONVERT(NUMERIC(22,0),CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),'1') + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),SUBSTRING(PATIENT_ID_NONNUM, 2, LEN(PATIENT_ID_NONNUM))))
WHERE SUBSTRING(PATIENT_ID_NONNUM, 1, 1) = 'M'
```

Comment: It looks like in your edit you're converting the string `1` to a string, then converting it to a number with a precision of 22 and a scale of 0, and the **ADDING** the substring of the `PATIENT_ID_NONNUM` column. If I'm not mistaken, since you're adding a string to a number, it will automatically convert both to a number and then add them (literally) together. In other words, you'll get the **SUM** of `1` and the substring of the `PATIENT_ID_NONNUM` column. That was why in my example I have the `1` in single quotes so that it gets concatenated rather than added.

Comment: I've verified that adding a string to a number results in the sum of 2 numbers or an error if the string cannot be converted to a number. In other words, `SELECT x = 1 + '1'` results in `x = 2`, not in `x = 11`. You need `SELECT x = CAST('1' + '1' AS NUMERIC(22,0))` for `x = 11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find [`STUFF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) (an often overlooked function) and `LEFT()` are a little more readable, but  others may disagree:

```
UPDATE [HIMC_I2B2_LZ-PROD].[dbo].[I2B2_SRC_BIOMETRICS]
SET PATIENT_ID = CAST(STUFF(PATIENT_ID_NONNUM, 1, 1, '1') AS NUMERIC(22,0))
WHERE LEFT(PATIENT_ID_NONNUM, 1) = 'M'
```

Comment: I always forget about `STUFF` and `LEFT` because I don't do enough with SQL any more :) +1

Comment: @NathanWheeler Well, it's really a matter of taste anyway. Most people are familiar with `SUBSTRING` but maybe not with `STUFF`, so you could argue that `SUBSTRING` is actually clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
UPDATE [HIMC_I2B2_LZ-PROD].[dbo].[I2B2_SRC_BIOMETRICS]
SET PATIENT_ID = CAST(('1' + SUBSTRING(PATIENT_ID_NONNUM, 2, LEN(PATIENT_ID_NONNUM) - 1)) AS NUMERIC(22,0))
WHERE SUBSTRING(PATIENT_ID_NONNUM, 1, 1) = 'M'
```

That's going to find all records where the first character is `M`, and replace the first character with a `1`. I haven't tested this, but I believe it should work properly.

I would also suggest not running this type of operation on a production database as a test, which I would assume is what the `-PROD` stands for in your catalog name.

EDIT: Since it seems important that this query comes out with the PATIENT_ID as a NUMERIC(22,0), I've added the necessary CAST.

Comment: The edit looks close, but seems to have a lot of pointless conversions.  I'll comment above.